# How wrapper class of Java is stored in HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, integer, wrapper

Please see the following code snippet.

```
Integer xInteger = new Integer(1);
map.put('c', xInteger);
xInteger++;
System.out.println(xInteger);  // 2
System.out.println(map.get('c')); // 1
System.out.println(xInteger == map.get('c')); // false
```

I'm aware that HashMap use an array of Node to store K,V objects. But here it looks like hashmap only stores the primitive value of the Integer? Because the value object retrieved from HashMap is not even the one we put before. Does anyone know how hashmap deal with the wrapper class?

Comment: Primitives and primitive wrapper objects are immutable. Same goes for strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changing in `xInteger` variable will not be reflected in the `HashMap` after `put` operation, because of the wrapper classes are **immutable**

> Once you assign a value to a variable(wrapper class type) you won't be able to change that value

---

, But if you are using any **mutable** classes like `AtomicInteger` the change will be reflected in the `HashMap`

For example:

```
        Map<Character, AtomicInteger> map = new HashMap<>();
        AtomicInteger xInteger = new AtomicInteger(1);
        map.put('c', xInteger);
        xInteger.incrementAndGet();
        System.out.println(xInteger); // 2
        System.out.println(map.get('c')); // 1
        System.out.println(xInteger == map.get('c'));
```

, output

```
2
2
true
```

More information: [Java Wrapper Classes are immutable? - Oracle community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2300660)

Answer (score 0):

As of Java 1.5, Java performs auto-unboxing to convert "wrapper types" such as Integer to the corresponding primitive type `int` when necessary. Then the increment operator can work on the resulting `int`.

When you do `xInteger++`, it performs that on the primitive `int`. Since primitive `int` is immutable (so is it's wrapper), it is not reflected when you do `System.out.println(map.get('c'))`.

---

Side note: You can directly write:

```
Integer xInteger = 1; // no need for boxing
```

Answer (score 0):

Primitives, primitive wrapper objects, and a number of other types (e.g. `java.lang.String`) are immutable in Java. Their internal state cannot be changed.

Doing `xInteger++` is, behind the scenes, effectively the same as:

```
int i = xInteger.intValue(); // get primitive value (unboxing)
i = i + 1;                   // assign new primitive value to variable
xInteger = Integer(i);       // create new object with updated value (boxing)
```

---

The only way to update the value of an `Integer` in a map, is to assign a new `Integer` to the map entry:

```
int i = 1;

map.put('c', i);   // will be auto-boxed to Integer
map.put('c', ++i); // will do i = i + 1, and auto-box the result to Integer
```